# Laravel - Illegal string offset

Tags: php, css, laravel, html-table, cell

I try to color table cell in laravel based on cell content but i keep getting this error:

> "Illegal string offset 'Disponible' (View: 
>       C:\Users\RAYLAN\Documents\CRMSAV\resources\views\
>       pagination_data.blade.php)
>       (View: C:\Users\RAYLAN\Documents\CRMSAV\re..."

This is my code:

```
@foreach($data as $row)
<tr>
 <td>{{ $row->ID_Piece }}</td>
 <td>{{ $row->Designation }}</td>
 <td style="background-color: {{ $row->Status['Disponible'] }}">
        {{ $row->Status }}
</td>
</tr>
{{$row->Status = array('Disponible' => '#FF0', 'N' => '#F0F')}}
@endforeach
<tr>
 <td colspan="3" align="center">
  {!! $data->links() !!}
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What is `$row->Status`? Is it an array containing the key `Disponsible`?

Comment: After the foreach loop there is no `$row` variable so it won't work

Comment: It's a row containing value 'Disponible' I get it's value from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do it with Jquery, here is the working solution :

```
@foreach($data as $row)
 <tr>
 <td>{{ $row->ID_Piece }}</td>
 <td>{{ $row->Designation }}</td>
 <td id="status">{{ $row->Status }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
<tr>
 <td colspan="3" align="center">
  {!! $data->links() !!}
 </td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#status').each(function(){
                if ($(this).text() == 'N') {
                    $(this).css('background-color','#f00');
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's saying that there is no `Disponible` in this line:

```
{{$row->Status = array('Disponible' => '#FF0', 'N' => '#F0F')}}
```

Perhaps write this on the line above and check what is in `$row->Status`:

```
<?php
dd( $row->Status );
?>
```

But it looks a bit wierd, to be honest. Remember that the double-mustaches ( `{{ $foobar }}` ) are echoing the content. But you're assigning a value in there... To something that you're looping through?!

Comment: You are so smart to admit that you are.

Answer (score 0):

**if your `$row->Status['Disponsible']` is present in all the rows then try the below**

```
<td style="background-color: {{ $row->Status['Disponible'] }}">
   {{ $row->Status['Disponsible'] }}
</td>
```

**EDIT:**
try to substitute for your `@foreach`loop

```
@foreach($data as $row)
 {{$row->Status = array('Disponible' => '#FF0', 'N' => '#F0F')}}
<tr>
 <td>{{ $row->ID_Piece }}</td>
 <td>{{ $row->Designation }}</td>
 <td style="background-color: {{ $row->Status['Disponible'] }}">
        {{ $row->Status['Disponible'] }}
</td>
</tr>

@endforeach
```

Comment: "syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')'"

Comment: Probably thats coming some other part of your code, check the line number in the error pops up and try to fix from there

Comment: delete that line

Comment: Now i get this: "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given...

Comment: I think you should try to put some effort in googling and fix the upcoming errors. If my answer helped you then don't hesitate to upvote. If you have another question try to post another question